# accessing a series of controls inside for loop

Tags: java, android

I have an array which contains some numbers:

```
int[] IDs = new int[] { 2, 5, 6, 11, 15};
```

There are many TextViews in Layout Resource:

```
TextView1;
TextView2;
TextView3;
TextView4;
TextView5;
TextView6;
```

and ... .

How Is it Possible to Access These in a for loop to (for example) change Their Text like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<IDs.length;i++){

 TextView[i].setText = "something";

}
```

problem:Eclipse Doesn't Recognize "TextView[i]".

Note:I want to change the text of those TextViews which their name ends with one of the numbers in the IDs array.

Comment: `TextView[i]` doesn't mean anything. When you create an array (e.g. the array of `int`s, `IDs`) then the `[i]` allows you to access the element at position `i`, e.g. `IDs[0]` would yield `2`. `TextView` is not an array, it's a type/class name.

Comment: what does the array IDs represent?

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this, this is assuming the `IDs` correspond to the id's of the text views, if not you have to create an array of the id's

```
int[] IDs = new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5};

TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(IDs[i])
textView.setText = "something";
```

If it's an activity, then remove the `rootView.`

Comment: I Haven't tested this code yet but I believe this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a given Layout, you can iterate over the children in your layout.
Just put all TextViews in one Layout.

For example:

```
    LinearLayout la = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++){
        if (la.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView){
            TextView tv = (TextView) la.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
It might be better to count the numbers of found TextViews, if you have other elements in your Layout. Otherwise it will not find all TextViews, if we only count to IDs.length.

Comment: It would be better to use `la.getChildCount()` instead of `IDs.length`.